# Kendo multiselect custom tagTemplate [UPDATE ]

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, dojo, kendo-multiselect

I figure it out how to displayit:
just inside for loop add:
 #:data.dataItems[idx].name#

I tried to make custom Kendo template to display data property "name" if one item is selected, it there is 2 or more ,then display count of total  item. I achieve that it displays id property:

http://dojo.telerik.com/ITeLU

And you can see it there is only one item selected, it displays id property:
[image: s]

but I want it to display name (text property from multiselect, ex: instead 232 display Oranges).

Does anyone has idea how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use dataTextField:"name" to show result according to name default it will be id try it and use dataValueField: "ProductID" for the id

Comment: Could you please show it on example? I attached link in my question.